# Getting the most significant words per document using R and the tm library

Tags: r, tm

I have a dataframe of 1400 rows `df` I create a corpus from the `text`column as such:

```
library(tm)
dc<-Corpus(VectorSource(df$text))
```

I then create the Document term matrix with tfidf weighting as such:

```
tm<-DocumentTermMatrix(dc,control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf))
```

I now want to reduce this dataset so that for each document I (1) remove words with a 0 weight (2) choose the 10 most significant words for that documents (highest weight).

However

```
as.data.frame(inspect(tm))
```

Results in the error

> Error: cannot allocate vectors of size 1.2 Gb

So any suggestions as to how to manipulate the `tm` without converting it?

To rephrase, for each document I want to pull out the 10 words with the highest tfidf weighting.